# Replace the time as 0's in datetime column

Tags: sql

Experts,
I need to convert the time value as 0's in a `datetime` column leaving behind `00:00:00.000`.

Sample data:

```
2019-04-17 08:47:51.433 
2019-04-17 00:00:00.000
```

Kindly suggest a key code.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @timbiegeleisen, I'm not sure is it a good idea to change the meaning of the original post. It was not clear is the OP wants to keep `00:00:00.000` or not.

Comment: @mitkosoft You're right, sorry, I fixed it.  For the record, my answer didn't even attempt to that anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As you appear to want to keep a time of `00:00:00.000` you could use

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2019-04-17 08:47:51.433' , '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00.000');
```

RESULT

```
2019-04-17 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: you missed `.000` part :)

Answer (score 0):

To trim the time part, you can just use [MySQL date function `DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date):

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3986ac9761529e1af42763750428edc2)**:

```
select DATE('2019-04-17 08:47:51.433')
```

```
| DATE('2019-04-17 08:47:51.433') |
| :------------------------------ |
| 2019-04-17                      |
```

Comment: I'm applying it for the whole column, few dates are with time and few dates are 0's. So I need in 1 pattern like 0's in time. The above method occurred an error i.e  'date' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @SathishJay . . . `date()` is indeed a built-in MySQL function.  Are you sure that is the database you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you really only want to *view* your datetime data this way.  If so, then you should use `DATE_FORMAT` with a mask containing only the date portion:

```
SELECT
    dt AS datetime,
    DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%Y-%m-%d') AS dateonly
FROM yourTable;
```

Unless you are certain that you would never need the time information, it makes no sense to throw that away.